# How to randomly select two strings?

Tags: php

I have decided to store the winner into another database table and then to use that to output the winner on another page... I have the following code but for some reason, my second query is not working and I have checked it through... All the variables are correct and my database table should be set up correctly:

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__.'/header2.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php?level1promo_competitions_winner=notlogin'>"; 
    exit();
} else {
    if($_SESSION['u_permission'] == 0) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level1promo_competitions_winner=nopermission'>"; 
       exit();
    } else {
        include_once __DIR__.'/includes/dbh.php';
        $level1promo_competitions_winner_form = strip_tags($_POST['level1promo_competitions_winner_form']);

        if ($level1promo_competitions_winner_form == $level1promo_competitions_winner_form) {


    $limit = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM level1promo_participants WHERE entry_id = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?;";

     $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
           echo "SQL error";
        } else {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $level1promo_competitions_winner_form, $limit);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
          $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);


          if($resultCheck < 1) {
              echo '<div class="nolevel1promo_competitions_winner">There are no Level 1 Promo Competition\'s Winner yet for that entry id</div>';
              exit();
          } else {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $useruid = $row['user_uid'];
                $email = $row['user_email'];

                echo $level1promo_competitions_winner_form;
                echo $useruid;
                echo $email;

                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO level1promo_winner (entry_id, user_uid, user_email) VALUES (?,?,?);";

                 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
                         echo "SQL statement failed";

                      } else {
                           //Bind parameters to the placeholder
                        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $levelpromo_competitions_winner_form, $useruid, $email);
                        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


                       echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level1promo_competitions_winner=success'>"; 
    }
}
}
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Please show the specific code causing the problem

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to ask... by the way your string concatenation is wrong --> 'string',function(),'string'... replace with a **dot** 'string'.function().'string'

Comment: sorry.... I will update my question above

Comment: which part of the code is wrong?

Comment: you mean for inside my table,,, it should be '..' instead of ',,'?

Comment: At the moment, I have two users in the database, shouldn't this return two names instead of one?

Comment: @piano0011, Your query is probabply ok, it should return all the data from `level1promo_participants` table. The problem is in this piece of code `                $strings = array($row['user_uid'],);` You are overwriting your `$strings` at each iteration of `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))`. Also  `array($row['user_uid'],);` creates a plain array with simple keys(0, 1, etc).

Comment: @piano0011 check my answer the code should be simple so that it will process fast. my answer will give the best result for your problem.

Comment: I got it.... I am surprised that a double quote does not work here but when I am using a single quote, it does work

Comment: echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=level1promo_competitions_winner_announcement.php?entry_id='.$row['entry_id'].'">';

Comment: I thought that a double quote should work because it should process all string variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by using below query. you don't need to put that much logic for it.

```
select column_name from table_name order by RAND() limit 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186742/discussion-on-answer-by-sayed-mohd-ali-how-to-randomly-select-two-strings).

Comment: just added a second queery but can't get it to insert into my database

Comment: if there is any other problem apart from above, ask a fresh question.

Comment: I found the problem... there was a typo

Comment: @piano0011 what problem eloborate